# JSON-RPC commands not working: Unexpected identifier

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have Geth running locally, and for whatever reason the JSON-RPC api is not working. Web3.js is working fine.

I've tried to start the console several ways:

`geth --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,admin,web3" --verbosity 0 --unlock 0 console`

I've also included the port and other combinations, such as starting RPC from within the console using `admin.startRPC(addr,host)`.

Each time I make an RPC call, for example:

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}'`

I get a variation of the following output:

`(anonymous): Line 1:9 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)`

I've also tried RPC calls omitting `-X POST` or specifying `rpcaddr:rpchost` at the end.

I don't have any other connections, or other geth-attached windows.

Answer (score 1):

To make an RPC call and get response, you need to initialize the target node with an **--rpcaddr** (IP Address) and an **--rpcport**. The default rpc port for geth is `8545`. You can also start this process from the interactive JavaScript console using `admin.startRPC(addr, port)`.

And while making an RPC call:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"method":"net_version","id":1}' rpcaddr:rpcport
```

Replace the *rpcaddr* with your IP address and *rpcport* with `8545` if you haven't modified it.

I have simulated the same commands and I got the result. Geth node is running on one terminal and I made an RPC call from another terminal. Check out this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I omitted the `rpcaddr:rpcport` in my question but I have tried variations specifying `localhost:8545' at the end. I'll try specifying my ip address at the beginning.

Comment: Yep, just to confirm I tried restarting with those instructions and curl still produces the same output.

Comment: Assuming you're making an RPC request from a different workstation, you need to mention the IP address of the target computer, not `localhost`

Comment: The RPC command examples use localhost. I also tried it with my ip address, and nope. Syntax error? Does it have to be a string?

Comment: Btw, I've also tried the approach of starting from within geth: `admin.startRPC(addr,port)` and that also didn't work. The output was: `listen tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8545: bind: cannot assign requested address`.

Comment: The syntax is correct. Just to make sure, are you running the geth node and RPC command on the same system? If yes, did you try using 127.0.0.1 as the `rpcaddr` in the curl command?

Comment: Yes. Still doesn't work. I'm running a full geth node and using the console directly on the same machine.

Comment: @Physes I updated the answer. Execute those commands and let me know what happens.

Comment: I tried it, but still `(anonymous): Line 1:9 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors)`. Think I'll raise an issue in GitHub. Could be my version- I'm running `Geth 1.4.5 -stable`.